# How do you prove the irreducibility of this multivariate polynomial?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

Let $p(x,y,z) = (x-r)^{2a} + (y-s)^{2b} + (z-t)^{2c}\in\Bbb Q[x,y,z]$ be a polynomial for some $a,b,c \geq 1$.  How do you prove that it's irreducible over $\Bbb{Q}$?

$r,s,t \in \Bbb{Q}, \neq 0$.

Comment: You can assume that $r,s,t=0$, since if $q(x,y,z)$ divides $p$, then $q(x+r,y+s,z+t)$ divides $p(x+r,y+s,z+t)$ & vice versa.

Comment: It suffices to prove that $x^{2a} + y^{2b} + z^{2c} \in \mathbb{Q}[x,y,z]$ is irreducible (because then after applying the automorphism $x \mapsto x-r, y \mapsto y-s, z \mapsto z-t$ we get $p$). By Eisenstein applied to the polynomial in $\mathbb{Q}[x,y][z]$ it suffices to prove that $x^{2a} + y^{2b} \in \mathbb{Q}[x,y]$ is irreducible. But I don't know how to proceed. The cases $a=1$ and $b=1$ are easy. Perhaps the complex factorization $(x^a + i y^b)(x^a - i y^b)$ helps.

Comment: Martin, if $a=b$ is odd, then $x^{2a}+y^{2a}$ is divisible by $x^2+y^2$. A similar thing ruins it whenever $\gcd(a,b)$ has an odd factor. I think it is essential that there are three terms here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, the polynomial is not always irreducible (imagine $a=b=c.$) Second, I think a good way is to substitute values of $y, z$ and use [Selmer's criterion for irreducibility of (univariate) trinomials.](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/138934/irreducibility-of-trinomials) I haven't gone through the details, but on quick glance it seems to work.

Comment: Why would it be reducible even if $a=b=c$?

Comment: @tomasz I think I was thinking about something different...

Comment: The polynomial is always irreducible! Anyway, can you elaborate on how one can use Nagell's result for trinomials in order to prove that the polynomial $x^{2a} + y^{2b} + z^{2c}$ is irreducible?